# Adding chai.js matchers in Typescript

Tags: typescript, chai

I'm using Chai.js in a Typescript project. It works fine until I try to add custom matchers to chai.

I'm adding it like this:

```
chai.use(function(chai, util) {
    chai.assertion.addMethod("failed", function () {
        new chai.Assertion(this._obj.isFailed).to.be.true();
    });
});
```

And it works fine, but when I try to transpile this expression:

```
expect(obj).to.have.failed();
```

I get

> error TS2339: Property 'failed' does not exist on type 'Assertion'.

Is there a better way to extend the chai matchers while avoiding type-checker errors?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [declaration merging](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#declaration-merging) to "extend" the Assertion interface in [chai.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/chai/chai.d.ts). In your example, you have to add to your project a .d.ts file (e.g. failed.d.ts) containing following declaration:

```
declare module Chai {
    interface Assertion {
        failed():Assertion;
    }
}
```

This will *add* the failed() method to the original Chai.Assertion interface.
Don't forget to reference it in your spec:

```
/// <reference path="typings/chai/chai.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="failed.d.ts"/>

...
expect(obj).to.have.failed();
```

Answer (score 22):

An update to @jiri-tobisek's answer: Using the up to date `@types/chai` package through npm, using simple imports instead of reference comments, to add helpers right now I need to wrap the augmentation in `declare global` or they're not detected.

That means, if declaring the types inline in a normal `.ts` file (e.g. alongside the custom matcher definition) I just add:

```
declare global {
    export namespace Chai {
        interface Assertion {
            responseText(expectedText: string): Promise<void>;
        }
    }
}
```

and if I want to put the types in their own type definition file (`my-custom-matcher.d.ts`), I use:

```
declare module 'chai' {
    global {
        export namespace Chai {
            interface Assertion {
                responseText(expectedText: string): Promise<void>;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! My mistake was not to have `declare global` and of course nothing was working.

Comment: declare global worked for me. I'm using this inside the test file which is using the `chai` helper method.

Comment: Still works, even with typescript@4.x, chai@4.x and @types/chai@4.x. I put the types in their own definitions files, which is included in `tsconfig.json`. Yet I didn't have to use `declare module 'chai'`, and I couldn't anyways, because it's a non-module now.